# Scanner as a method parameter

Tags: java, file

I have just started to practice with txt files in java, and I have an issue - I need to make a method with scanner as a parameter and I have no clue how it should be done. At this moment I made it without any parameter and It's working fine, but the task was to make it  Scanner.

```
public static void flipCoins() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    File file = new File(name);
    String bufor;

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            int heads = 0;
            int tails = 0;
            int total = 0;
            bufor = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] bufor1 = bufor.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < bufor1.length; i++) {
                bufor1[i] = bufor1[i].toLowerCase();
                if (bufor1[i].equals("h")) {
                    heads++;
                    total++;
                } else if (bufor1[i].equals("t")) {
                    tails++;
                    total++;
                }

            }
            double percent = ((double)heads / (double)total);
            percent = percent * 100;
            percent = Math.round(percent);
            System.out.println(heads + " heads " + "(" + percent + "%).");
            if (heads > tails) {
                System.out.println("There were more heads!");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("error");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand how to make anything a method parameter? Do you know what a method parameter is?

Comment: `public static void flipCoins(Scanner scanner) {` and in main method (or callee) you create scanner instance what you do in flipCoins and pass that on while calling the `flipCoins` method?

Comment: Yeah, I understand how to use for example String as method parameter. But the thing is, when I'm using scanner as a parameter and trying to call it, java tells me to put something between the bars.

Comment: @Paweł Show your attempt at solving it so we can tell exactly where the problem is. And show how you're trying to call flipCoins.

Comment: Im trying to recreate existing code posted above to make it work with this task:
https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/java/fileio/flipCoins

and i dont really know how should I use this scanner parameter

Sorry for being not understandable, that's the hardest part of coding for me :p

Comment: @Paweł Again, show what you've tried. You said you tried making it a parameter but got an error. Show you trying to make it a parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I have figured it out.
Just needed to remove 
String name = scanner.nextLine();
File file = new File(name);
and it has been accepted (still don't know why it's working tho :D)